# xBones disappearing when moved in edit mode

Tags: blender

I was animating my character and was moving around the bones in edit mode. I accidentally moved a bone in edit mode, by pressing "M". I moved the bone into the second layer in edit mode. Then, I realized my mistake and tried to move it back to the first layer. I hit "M" again to bring back up the layer selector, but when I clicked on the first layer, I could still not see the bone. I tried moving the missing bone to all the layers, but it stayed hidden. I selected the bone from the Outliner, but it still was missing. The bone is hidden in all modes, but the bone still affects the mesh in animations.

I assume I am doing something wrong. I have provided a picture to help. The bone missing is named "fr" for front-right.

[- Image in case it helps -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTxZQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read How do I ask  a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what do you mean by "bone is hidden in all modes", do you mean it is hidden in all layers?